# How to improve these two function to take less time on giving result?

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate all roots of polynomial (assume that all roots are real). I wrote two functions `laguerre.m` which uses Laguerre's method to calculate a root of polynomial and `allroots.m` which combines Laguerre's method and reduction to give all roots of polynomial.

Here's my `laguerre.m` file:

```
function y = laguerre(koef,x0,delta,maxsteps)

if nargin < 3, delta = eps; end
if nargin < 4, maxsteps = 50; end

n = length(koef);
steps = 0;

while (abs(polyval(koef,x0)) > delta) && (steps < maxsteps)
    steps = steps + 1;
    fvalue = polyval(koef,x0); %polynomial value at x0
    first = polyval(polyder(koef),x0);  %first derivative value at x0 
    second = polyval(polyder(polyder(koef)),x0);
    g = first/fvalue;
    h = g^2 - second/fvalue;
    den1 = g + sqrt((n-1)*(n*h-g^2)); %denominator with +
    den2 = g - sqrt((n-1)*(n*h-g^2)); %denominator with -
    if abs(den1) > abs(den2)
        d = den1;
    else
        d = den2;
    end
    a = n/d;
    x0 = x0-a;
end
y = x0;
```

And here's my `allroots.m` file:

```
function y = allroots(koef,x0)

result = [];
while length(koef) > 0
    x = laguerre(koef,x0);
    result = [x result];
    koef = deconv(koef,[1 -x]);
end
y = result;
```

But it seems that MATLAB needs to much time to give the result. How can I improve my code?
Example of input data that I used: `allroots([16 0 -1000 650 1524],-5)`.

Comment: This is my input : `allroots([16 0 -1000 650 1524],-5)`, I didn't input data for `delta` and `maxsteps`. _Have you profiled your code to find the bottle-neck?_ - sorry, I don't really understand what are you asking.

Comment: It's an infinite loop, `coef` never gets empty so `length(coef)` is always `>0`.

Comment: You can read the documentation for how to [profile your code](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html), which will show the execution time and number of calls for every line of code, letting you isolate and fix the worst offenders. You should also do some more basic debugging to address the infinite loop case raised by @saastn